How to handle many checkboxes mapped
I'm building a feature where each item in a mapped list has a checkbox. I store the IDs of checked items in a separate array (or Set) and use this data to control the checked state of each checkbox. I'm also persisting the selection across pages using sessionStorage.
The issue is that there's a noticeable lag, nearly a full second, between clicking a checkbox and seeing it visually update.
I've tried the following without success:

Using new Set() instead of an array for storing IDs
Wrapping the state management of the checked items in useCallback and values in React.memo

None of these have improved the performance. I feel like I might be overlooking a larger architectural or state management detail, but I'm stumped. Any advice or tips would be greatly appreciated!
Below is a very simplified example. In the actual code, the checkbox component is nested three levels deep, which might be contributing to the lag:
interface Item {
  document_id: string;
  source_index: string;
}

const SearchResultItems: React.FC = () => {
  // Simulate a list of results with document IDs and source indices
  const results = Array.from({ length: 1000 }, (_, index) => ({
    document_id: `doc-${index}`,
    source_index: `src-${index}`,
  }));

  const [checkedItems, setCheckedItems] = useState<Set<string>>(() => {
    const savedItems = sessionStorage.getItem("checkedItems");
    return savedItems ? new Set(JSON.parse(savedItems)) : new Set();
  });

  // Function to handle checkbox toggle
  const toggleCheckbox = (documentId: string) => {
    setCheckedItems((prevCheckedItems) => {
      const updatedCheckedItems = new Set(prevCheckedItems);
      if (updatedCheckedItems.has(documentId)) {
        updatedCheckedItems.delete(documentId);
      } else {
        updatedCheckedItems.add(documentId);
      }
      return updatedCheckedItems;
    });
  };

  // Save to session storage on change
  React.useEffect(() => {
    sessionStorage.setItem("checkedItems", JSON.stringify(Array.from(checkedItems)));
  }, [checkedItems]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Search Results</h2>
      <ul>
        {results.map((item) => (
          <li key={item.document_id}>
            <label>
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                checked={checkedItems.has(item.document_id)}
                onChange={() => toggleCheckbox(item.document_id)}
              />
              {item.document_id}
            </label>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SearchResultItems;

---- UPDATE
Looking at it more I am using Elastic search-ui library and they handle the mapping with this component import { Results } from "@elastic/react-search-ui" so I think the issues lies there with them re-rendering everything when one checkbox is selected.
Here is an example, the checkbox is within the CustomSearchResultView component
import { Results } from "@elastic/react-search-ui";
 
const ResultsList = ({
  checkedItems,
  setCheckedItems,
}) => {
  return (
 <Results
        resultView={(resultView) => (
          <CustomSearchResultView
            resultView={resultView}
            checkedItems={checkedItems}
            setCheckedItems={setCheckedItems}
            key={resultView.result.id.raw}
          />
        )}
      />
  );
};


I don't see anything wrong with this code. It's pretty standard way to handle checkboxes. I pasted your component into sandbox and I don't experience any performance issues.
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/objective-leaf-vglk52?file=%2Fsrc%2FSearchResultItems.tsx%3A47%2C25
Most likely the issues is elsewhere.

I edited my original post, I think you're right and the problem lies within the @elastic/react-search-ui library or something I'm missing with using it
